# Getting VSFTP running on Fedora 14

Tags: linux, fedora, ftp

Having troubles getting VSFTPD running on Fedora 14. Here is what I have done so far, please let me know if I am missing something. When I try to connect through FTP it says connection time out.

Installed VSFTP with yum

```
yum install vsftpd
```

Edited config file

```
vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Started service and made sure it would always start up

```
service vsftpd start
chkconfig vsftpd on
```

Added and configured a new user

```
/usr/sbin/useradd upload
/usr/bin/passwd upload
usermod -c "This user cannot login to a shell" -s /sbin/nologin upload
```

Added firewall rules

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Checked netstat (In reply to comment below)

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      23752/vsftpd
```

Comment: Anything in the logs?  Anything related to vsftpd in `netstat -anpt` output?

Comment: Is SELinux running in enforcing mode? Does temporarily disabling it solve the problem?

Comment: CJC: Nothing shows up in tail -f error_log when I try to connect, and netstat is pasted above.   KENNY: No idea what that is, I am somewhat novice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the parameter listen_address in vsftpd.conf ?
can you disable iptapbles and try to connect ?
Can you take tcp traces on your ftp server when you try to connect from another server ?
can you try ftp localhost ?